# Why is my wireless mouse so noisy?

Tags: wireless-networking, mouse, noise

I have wireless Microsoft Natural 7000 mouse & keyboard. I've noticed a scratchy high pitch noise that comes from mouse if I put it against my ear (don't ask). It changes if I click a button or mouse register any movement.

Why may that be?

Comment: I've experiencing something similar with a Microsoft Wireless Mobile Mouse 4000.  I can barely hear it but it's enough to annoy me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possibly it is one of the components with electrical current at that particular frequency going through it making a mechanical vibration. My guess is you're young! Oldsters like me wouldn't hear it :)
If you really want to track it down use a screwdriver or similar against your ear (as a stethoscope) to listen to individual components.

Answer (score 1):

May be there a small short of wires inside the mouse . if you can remove the cover and clear it can can solved